# MySQL, Excel, and Windows Calculator show different results for same expression

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula, rounding, calculated-columns

I am rounding a number to 4 decimal places. I am trying to copy an Excel calculation but seeing a different result in MySQL.

Excel formula:  `=($F$6/100)*G29*L29` where **$F$6** = 5, **G29** = 59.23  and **L29** = 58.3

On Excel I get 172.6576
On a Windows Calculator I get 172.65545
Using MySQL I get 172.6555

Following in a for loop:

```
SELECT ID, lookupprocess.PROJID, PRICE, SUM(abs( FSP-LSP)) AS ABS, SUM(((abs( FSP-LSP))*SI)/1000) AS KM_Completed, count(lookupprocess_id) AS NoOfLines, (".$countcompleted[0]['count']."/$countJobs)*100 AS TotalPercent, SUM(((abs( FSP-LSP))*SI)/1000) * PRICE AS TotalPrice
                FROM hdb.lookupprocess
                left join jobsprocesscomplete on ID = lookupprocess_id
                left join detailsseismic on jobsprocesscomplete.JOBNO = detailsseismic.JOBNO
                left join biditems on biditems_id  = ITEMID
                where lookupprocess.PROJID = ".$model->PROJID."
                    AND ID = $k
```

Do PHP and JavaScript comply with Excel formulas/calculations?

Comment: The Windows calc & MySQL are the same - mysql is rounding to 4 decimals in your example, so the .6555 is what you would get when rounding .65545.  No idea on excel.

Comment: ok, but i need to know where the difference from excel comes from.

Comment: these are formatted currency 4 decimal places. after checking and changing one cell from 2 decimal to 4 i get `172.7316` after changing the whole spreadsheet to general formatting i get `172.7294875`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or to put it another way, one or more of the values in F6, G29 and L29 in Excel is slightly more than it appears to be when rounded or truncated for display purposes.

Comment: i have realized once i formatted everything to general formatting, however even after fixing the figures they are still off.